# Format @param phpdoc-tag in eclipse with whitespaces

Tags: comments, whitespace, eclipse-juno, phpdoc, eclipse-pdt

I am using Eclipse Juno and PDT. With the PHP Formatter i am formatting my code. I have created an own formatter preset based on the PSR-2 template.

### Problem

I cant find any configuration option to keep the whitespaces in `@param` phpDoc comments.

Before code formatter:

```
/**
 *
 * @param string $sName              name value
 * @param mixed  $sValueWithLongName value
 */
```

After code formatter:

```
/**
 *
 * @param string $sName name value
 * @param mixed $sValueWithLongName value
 */
```

How can i keep the whitespaces **without** using the `@formatter:off` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On juno (PDT 3.1) you can't.

You need PDT 3.3.2. In option's you'll find "disable phpdoc formatting".